# How to find the max of continuous subarray of size k

Tags: python

`l = [2,1,5,1,3,2]`

subarrays are `[2,1,5], [1,5,1], [5,1,3], [1,3,2]`

output is `[5 ,1 ,3]` which is 9

My code is

```py
def maxcosu(arr,k):
    maxtotal = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)-k):
        total = 0
        for j in range(i, i+k):
            total = total + arr[j]
        maxtotal = max(maxtotal, total)
    return maxtotal
maxcosu([2,1,5,1,3,2] , 3)
```

But for `[1,1,1,8,8,8]` my expected output is 24, but I am getting 17.

I have gone through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264189/to-find-max-continuous-subarray-sum-of-size-m) and the answer by *zeeshan12396* is wrong for test case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about your solution, I guess you should have passed `len(arr)-k+1` instead of `len(arr)-k` to `range` builtin.

Here is one-liner solution using List-Comprehension to get continuous sub-array of length `k` for maximum `sum`:

```py
>>> max((l[i:i+k] for i in range(len(l)-k+1)), key=sum)
[8, 8, 8]
```

And to get the maximum sum:

```py
>>> max((sum(l[i:i+k]) for i in range(len(l)-k+1)))
24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

arr =[1,1,1,8,8,8]
k = 3

list = []
iterations = len(arr) + 1 - k


for i in range(iterations):
    list.append(arr[0+i:k+i])
print(list)

suml = []

for l in list:
    suml.append(math.fsum(l))
print(suml)

max_val = max(suml)
print(max_val)

max_idx = suml.index(max_val)
print(max_idx)

correct_arr = list[max_idx]
print(correct_arr)
```

I think this is what you are looking for?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, I have got:

```
def maxcosu(arr,k):
    sub_arr_sum = []
    for i in range(len(arr)-k+1):
        sub_arr_sum.append(sum(arr[i:i+k]))
    return max(sub_arr_sum)
```